# Server on Android phone

Tags: android, api, service

I want to have an active service on my android phone.
This server will be available from clients in my local network.
Communication can be any (for example a rest api service on android)

In other words I want my service to handle external push notification but from local network not GCM.

What are know approaches to achieve this?

Comment: may be this link can be a bit of help:  http://lifehacker.com/5920173/use-your-android-phone-as-a-full-fledged-web-server